# Show $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{int}\mathrm dt=0$ for all $n\neq0$

Tags: complex-integration

I am struggling to see how this result holds for non-integer $n$ because $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{int}\mathrm dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}[\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)]\mathrm dt$$ and this works out to be
$$\frac{\sin(2\pi n)}{n}+i\left(-\frac{\cos(2\pi n)}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and I only see this equaling $0$ when $n$ is an integer not equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly common for $n$ to denote an integer.  Preumably what was meant was to show this for all *integers* $n>0$.  As you've observed, it's not true for arbitrary real $n$.

Comment: but cant we use Cauchy's theorem to say it is true for all n not 0?

Comment: No, because it isn't true for non-integer $n$.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is about integrating the value of an analytic function around a closed path.  For non-integer $n$ there's no way to view this integral as the path integral of any analytic function around a closed path.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a non-zero real number then $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{int}\, dt \equiv \frac {e^{i2n\pi}-1} {in}=0$ if and only if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: but cant we use Cauchy's theorem to say it is true for all n not 0?

Comment: @DLB $z^{n}$ is multi-valued in general. It is single valued and analytic when $n$ is an integer. So Cauchy's Theorem does not apply when $n$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are perfectly right! For arbitrarely $n$  the given equality does not hold. One may note that your final expression can also be written as

$$\frac{\sin(2\pi n)}{n}+i\left(-\frac{\cos(2\pi n)}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac1{in}(e^{2\pi in}-1)$$

Since $e^{2\pi in}=1$ for all integer $n$ $($beside $n=0$$)$ we can conclude that the integral equals indeed zero.

> $$\therefore~\int_0^{2\pi}e^{int}\mathrm dt~=~0~~~,\forall n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$$